# How does Document Chunking with Text Splitter and Vectorizing maintain the context of the overall document?

Tags: vectorization, text-chunking

When I use a text splitter it randomly chops the document mid-sentence. After vectorizing it, how does semantic search able to fetch the relevant chunks even though the splitting is causing a loss of context?